# queryset to dict with common fields as keys

Tags: python, django

Given a queryset like this:

```
[<'item', 'category1'>, <'item2', 'category1'>, <'item3', 'category2'>]
```

What is the Pythonic way to 'zip' this to a dict where the common categories are the keys, with values as lists? e.g.

```
{ category1: [item, item2], category2: [item3] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `defaultdict`.  If a key does not exist in a dictionary it returns a default-constructed item.  Below it returns an empty list, so each item can be appended without special handling for a non-existing key.

```
from collections import defaultdict
D = defaultdict(list)
data = [('item', 'category1'), ('item2', 'category1'), ('item3', 'category2')]

for item,category in data:
    D[category].append(item)
print(D)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'category2': ['item3'], 'category1': ['item', 'item2']})
```

Comment: Wow, defaultdict is exactly what I needed - very elegant. Thank you very much Mark.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure their is a cleaner approach, but the following should certainly work:

```
qs = [('item', 'category1'), ('item2', 'category1'), ('item3', 'category2')]
for item, cat in qs:
if cat not in cat_dict:
    cat_dict[cat] = []
cat_dict[cat].append(item)
```